# Certificate null error on local azure service fabric

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric, x509certificate

Trying to run Azure Service Fabric application on my local, all services are running except one which throws certificate cannot be null exception.Below is code snippet to get certificate.

Have installed certificate on my local for local machine and current user.

[image]

[image]

```
/// <summary>
/// Finds the ASP .NET Core HTTPS development certificate in development environment. Update this method to use the appropriate certificate for production environment.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Returns the ASP .NET Core HTTPS development certificate</returns>
private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificateFromStore()
{
    string aspNetCoreEnvironment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
    if (string.Equals(aspNetCoreEnvironment, "Development", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        const string aspNetHttpsOid = "1.3.6.1.4.1.311.84.1.1";
        const string CNName = "CN=localhost";
        using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
        {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            var certCollection = store.Certificates;
            var currentCerts = certCollection.Find(X509FindType.FindByExtension, aspNetHttpsOid, true);
            currentCerts = currentCerts.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerDistinguishedName, CNName, true);
            return currentCerts.Count == 0 ? null : currentCerts[0];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("GetCertificateFromStore should be updated to retrieve the certificate for non Development environment");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to copy the cert files to a location where the Service Fabric service account can pick them up on startup, and either read them directly, 
or write them to `**new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)**` for subsequent use.

Check this doc for further reference:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/cross-platform-cryptography.md#x509store

and please ensure you are not following the one of the mentioned scenario.

You can use a `[SetupEntryPoint][1]` that runs as a user with `**AccountType="LocalSystem"**` to run the `SetupEntryPoint`

Alternatively , you can use Azure key vault to store the certificate and then read it from there. You can find sample code here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/how-to-managed-identity-service-fabric-app-code#accessing-key-vault-from-a-service-fabric-application-using-managed-identity

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for input i have updated the question and added a little more detail but still getting same exception